# VBA MsgBox causes an erro

Tags: vba, excel

In my VBA project I have the occasional MsgBox pop up to notify the user something has 'Completed' or 'Updated' after a subroutine has run. 
It seems to run okay without the MsgBox, but inserting one seems to give me an error. 
Not sure if it's necessary to display the entire code here as it's quite big but at the end of a subroutine I simply want ...

```
MsgBox ("Completed")
```

which is followed by the End Sub

However when I run this and then click on OK on the Msgbox, I get a runtime error which on clicking DeBug, it highlights the End Sub.

Is there any reason why having this would throw up such an error? 
Am I missing something from it? 
Many thanks

Some of the code here

```
'Add unique data to new location
For i = 1 To UnqArray1.Count
 rCell(i, 1) = UnqArray1(i)
Next

'Move Split Array into a new array
Set rTable2 = rCell
rng2() = rTable2.Value

'Filter into unique items
On Error Resume Next
For Each b In rng2
UnqArray2.Add b, b
Next

'Clear location
rCell.Clear

'Add new array to location
For i = 1 To UnqArray2.Count
rCell(i, 1) = UnqArray2(i)
Next

'Find the end of the category list
lastrow = Worksheets("CatMatch").Range("Q100000").End(xlUp).Row

'Sort alphabetically
Worksheets("CatMatch").Range("Q1:Q" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("Q1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

'Copy it to CatMatch
Worksheets("CatMatch").Range("Q1:Q" & lastrow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("CatMatch").Range("B15")

MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub
```

Comment: It depends where in the code the message box is. Perhaps post a bit more code so we can see what else is happening! Note: Post the code in your original question rather than in a comment. Perhaps the last 10 - 20 lines of code might be enough??

Comment: And what *is* the error?

Comment: It should be `MsgBox "Completed"` (with no parenthesis) since you aren't using the return value of `MsgBox` --  though that doesn't explain why your code is throwing an error.

Comment: I've tried without parenthesis. The error is "Code execution has been interrupted". When I click on Debug it highlights the End Sub. I've added some of the code in the original question. Thanks all for the comments.

Comment: Try it without `On Error Resume Next`. That line should seldom be used. It makes debugging very difficult.

Comment: The only thing I can think is that you are running it from the VBA editor. The `MsgBox` causes the Excel window itself to pop up briefly, but an error in your code (which `On Error Resume Next` is hiding) means Excel can't update its screen coherently. The VBA interpreter raises a fatal error  -- but because of `On Error Resume Next` it can't put that error anywhere before `End Sub`. Maybe without the `MsgBox` you still have a problem but some VBA interpreter cleanup allows the screen to be updated coherently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error, but you are almost certainly incorrect that it runs okay without the `MsgBox`. The problem is that the problem with your code is being hidden by `On Error Resume Next` in the fragment:

```
'Filter into unique items
On Error Resume Next
For Each b In rng2
UnqArray2.Add b, b
Next
```

Two comments:

1) Why not use the [RemoveDuplicates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238869(v=office.12).aspx) method if that is what you are trying to do?

2) Your code is using the fact that a collection throws an error if you try to add a duplicate key. This *is* a valid use of `On Error Resume Next` -- but only if you *turn it off* when you are done adding keys to the collection. Something like:

```
On Error Resume Next
    For Each b In rng2
        UnqArray2.Add b, b
    Next
On Error GoTo 0
```

A good habit to get into is to consider `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` as defining a block of code, perhaps even indenting the code inside the block as I did above. An even better habit is to not assume that only 1 type of error can happen. The above code is expecting that error `457` might arise (this is the error number corresponding to trying to add a duplicate key -- you need to search documentation to find it, or just run your code without the error handling and see how it crashes). Anything else indicates some other problem. To be maximally safe you can do something like:

```
On Error Resume Next
    For Each b In rng2
        UnqArray2.Add b, b
        If Err.Number > 0 And Err.Number <> 457 Then
            MsgBox "Unhandled error: " & Err.Number
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
On Error GoTo 0
```

Doing this won't solve your problem, but should make your actual problem more apparent.

Comment: Thank you John for that explanation and tip. It makes total sense. Added the On Error GoTo 0 has seem to have stopped the error pop ups and the program seems to be working as it should. Many many thanks.

Comment: @user3683463 I'm glad that it helped and the tip is important to keep in mind -- but I have absolutely no idea how that fixed the error. It almost seems like something about your code triggered a bug in the VBA interpreter itself. If it pops up again (without being hidden by an `On Error Resume Next`) you could always post a new question.